# What should there be at the root resource of a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Requesting '/cats' to an API returns a collection of cats, while requesting '/cats/123' returns the cat whose id is '123'

My question is: what should be the response when '/' (the root of the API) is requested?

An index with the names of all the collections in the API maybe?

Comment: If you want a developer friendly message then I would suggest using the built in or third party documentation tools which produce documentation that can be locked down from external access. The api root should return 404 as nothing resides there, correct?

Comment: There's a RFC draft proposing a "home document" format for REST APIs: [Home Documents for HTTP APIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-nottingham-json-home-06).

Answer (score 5):

There is probably no objective answer to that one, but a cool API should be browseable. That means, given a start URI it should be possible to "discover" the API in its full, therefore it would definitely help to have a root resource that links to all the different parts of your API.

Even if all the services are separate applications (think microservices), I would still create one service to have the "start" links to all, to really have one entry point into the whole application.

And I mean not just for humans to browse through, but clients would also start from the very first URI. Always, except when using bookmarks to previous states (and those bookmarks need maintained when given redirects, or not founds).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a set convention for this. It depends on what you want to provide, and what your security concerns are. You might consider returning a list of valid objects in the REST API. Or if you don't want to reveal that information to just anyone, consider returning 204 or 404.